# remember form tag input values

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to create a filter form that user selects dates and sources. The problem is after clicking submit button, in the new page i see that input values are empty. Is there a way to make form remember its values ? Thanks.

```
<%= form_tag products_path, :method => 'get' do %>

<%= text_field_tag :from %>
<%= text_field_tag :to %>

<% Source.all.each do |source| %>
 <%= check_box_tag "sources[]", source.id %>
 <%= source.name %><br />
<% end %>

<%= submit_tag "Submit", :name => nil %>

<% end %>
```

controller

```
def index

 @from = params[:from] ? params[:from].to_datetime : (Time.now-3.day)
 @to = params[:to] ? params[:to].to_datetime : (Time.now)
 @sources = params[:sources] ? params[:sources] : 1..6

 @products = Product.where(:source_id => @sources, :created_at => @from.beginning_of_day..@to.end_of_day)

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you use the value and checked options from these tags? Here is an example :

```
<%= form_tag products_path, :method => 'get' do %>

<%= text_field_tag :from, @from %>
<%= text_field_tag :to, @to %>

<% Source.all.each do |source| %>
 <%= check_box_tag "sources[]", source.id, @sources.include?( source.id ) %>
 <%= source.name %><br />
<% end %>

<%= submit_tag "Submit", :name => nil %>

<% end %>
```